# Configure email forwarding using Office 365 API

Tags: office365api

Can i Configure email forwarding using Office 365 API?

Below link show manual process, i want to do same thing programatically

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Configure-email-forwarding-in-Office-365-ab5eb117-0f22-4fa7-a662-3a6bdb0add74

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by the Graph API:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/mailfolder-post-messagerules?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

You will also need an application-level authorization (client-credentials grant) to authorise all users in the Exchange Server domain:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow